# Stop query when SUM is reached (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a database with colums I am working on.  What I am looking for is the date associated with the row where the SUM(#) reaches 6 in a query.  The query I have now will give the date when the number in the colum is six but not the sum of the previous rows.  example below

```
Date     number
----     ------
6mar16    1
8mar16    4
10mar16   6
12mar16   2
```

I would like to get a query to get the 10mar16 date because on that date the number is now greater than 6.  Earlier dates wont total up to six.

Here is an example of a query i have been working on:

```
SELECT max(date) FROM `numbers` WHERE `number` > 60
```

Comment: Not very clear what you ask for. Can you be a bit more comprehensive in your question? Example input, example output and what you tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this query, which tracks the accumulated sum and then returns the first one that meets the condition:

```
select   date
from     (select * from mytable order by date) as base,
         (select @sum := 0) init
where    (@sum := @sum + number) >= 6
limit 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/382e3/8)

Comment: I used your code.  It worked great.  thanks for the help.  I would never have thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

Most databases support ANSI standard window functions.  In this case, cumulative sum is your friend:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(number) over (order by date) as sumnumber
      from t
     ) t
where sumnumber >= 10
order by sumnumber
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In MySQL, you need variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@sumn := @sumn + number) as sumnumber
      from t cross join (select @sumn) params
      order by date
     ) t
where sumnumber >= 10
order by sumnumber
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: I used the first answer given and it is working awesome.  Thanks for your help.  I'm always learning things from you guys.

Comment: It is great that the answer works.  But, if the first answer works, then you are not using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome!!!!  It seems to be working great.  Here is the code that I used.

```
SELECT  date, id, crewname
FROM     (select * FROM flightrecord WHERE `crewname` = 'brayn' 
ORDER BY dutyTimeArrive DESC) as base,
         (select @sum := 0) init
WHERE    (@sum := @sum + tankDropCount) >= 6
limit 1
```